# How can iterator be run in reverse order?

Tags: c++, vector

The following loop allows an iterator display some data values in a forward direction. Show how a loop could display values in reverse order (using -- instead of ++)
Be careful! It is incorrect just to swap begin and end.

```
 for (iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); ++iter)
 cout << *iter;
```

Comment: You should use [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [`rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend)

Comment: or you can use `std::reverse(data.begin(), data.end())` first

Answer (score 1):

There are already reverse iterators defined for STL containers:

```
for (auto iter = ctnr.rbegin(); iter != ctnr.rend(); ++iter) {
    cout << *iter;
}
```